# chained selection using drop down

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

in this code below im printing a list of subjects from the database into a dropdown. When a subject is selected, the next drop down called section should display the sections each of subject by looking up for the subject name in the database.

This is what i was able to do but it did not work, any help people and please ignore my style of coding since i am a beginner. Thank you in advance.

main code:

```
    <div>
      Subject:
  <?php
        $conn = new mysqli('fgdfgfg', 'fggfdgfr', 'fgfgf', 'fgfgfgf') or die('Cannot connect to db');
        $result = $conn->query("select name from class");
        echo "<select name='subject' nChange='getSection('findsection.php?subject='+this.value)'>";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            unset($id, $name);
            $name = $row['name'];
            echo '<option value="subject">' . $name . '</option>';
        }
        echo "</select>";
        ?> 
    </div>
    <br>  
    <div id="sectiondiv">
        Section: 
        <select name="select">
        </select>
    </div>
```

findsection.php

```
<? $subject=intval($_GET[‘subject’]);;
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "fhdfhdfhf";
$password = "ghhfghgh";
$dbname = "ghghgh";
$mysqli  = new Mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or mysqli_error($mysqli);
$section = $mysqli->query("SELECT section FROM class WHERE name = '$subject'")->fetch_object()->section; 
$result=mysql_query($section);?>
<select name="section">
<? while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
   <option value><?=$row['section']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSection(strURL)
{         
 var req = getXMLHTTP(); // fuction to get xmlhttp object
 if (req)
 {
  req.onreadystatechange = function()
 {
  if (req.readyState == 4) { //data is retrieved from server
   if (req.status == 200) { // which reprents ok status                    
     document.getElementById('sectiondiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
  }
  else
  { 
     alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n");
  }
  }            
  }        
req.open("GET", strURL, true); //open url using get method
req.send(null);
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: make it correct nChange='getSection it would be onchange='getSection

Comment: you could be more explicit at what point your code stops workong. Yes maybe javascript function did'nt get called, or maybe XHR or even database errored. You must come up with ways to debug. (alerts console log responces.. firebug tool etc,..)

Comment: @saty fixed but still the code won't work as must.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the line

```
<select name='subject' onchange='getSection('findsection.php?subject='+this.value)'>
```

`this.value` is not being passed as you want it to. The value of `this` here is an `window` object not the `select` tag object.

So I suggest you to get the value of current value in the `getSection` function itself and form the url inside the function and then do the http request.

Comment: aww thank you for the help but im not that good lol. hmm any small guidance tips?

Comment: I think the best way to debug a code is to first localize the area where the bug might have occurred. In javascript you can use console.log function for that to print out the logs on the web console at each step of the program.